# Can't mount raid 1 with different size disks

Tags: amazon-ec2, raid, mdadm

I have a EC2 instance with a an ssd on xvdm (20 gb, 60 iops) and another ssd on xvdb (16 gb, better iops - instance store). The xvdm contains a mysql database and I'm trying to join these 2 disks in a raid 1 with write-behind to the slower disk. So I do

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --size=15995392 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 \
--bitmap=internal --write-behind=1024 --assume-clean missing \
--write-mostly /dev/xvdm
```

I've set the size manually so that I can add smaller xvdb:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/xvdb
```

I then see `Rebuild status` in `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` and once it finished rebuilding, I try to mount it with `mount /dev/md0 /mnt/mysql` but get:

```
mount: /dev/md0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

`dmesg | tail` does not seem to have anything useful.

I can't change the size of the fast xvdb by ec2 design, and don't want to change the size of the bigger `xvdm` because ec2 limits iops to 3X volume size in GB and even though I'm not going to use the additional (20 - 16) 4 GB of space, I still want to have and pay for the iops - it's cheaper than provisioned iops magnetic volume.

So why does not linux let me use the raid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to create a file system.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
```

or something like that.

Comment: There is an fs, but it's weird - I've got a 2 gb snapshot, when I create a 20 gb volume from it - I get the error I've posted, but when I make a 2 gb volume, it works ok.